# How to monitoring a process on android

Tags: android, netlink, process-monitoring

Does someone know if it is possible to dump all writes of a process does in the fileystem in android? Or at least the path where the process writes?

I would like to monitor my application. I see the dalvik machine use netlink class to comunicate with kernel, should I edit that or something else?

Comment: Which process do you want to monitor? Your own app?

Comment: Yes I have an app and i would like know what/where it write in the filesystem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Lollipop you can use the API App Usage Statistics. For pre-lollipop devices you can use getRecentTasks() from ActivityManager

Comment: And this give all the interaction with the filesystem?

Comment: You can write in the filesystem with the way you prefer all the data you retrieve